# 1D heatmap with double squares on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I use this code to generate a 1D heatmap:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('seaborn')

data = np.array([0.8373871, 0.48286343, 0.11166477, 0., 0.07306099, 1.,
                     0.8604202, 0.59167194, 0.60088444, 0.32089615]).reshape(1, 10)
plt.imshow(data, cmap='Reds')
plt.xlabel('Timesteps', weight='bold', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

The output graph:
[image]

if you can notice, if though I have 1 d array, the graph generates double squares on `Y` axis instead of one. How can I keep only one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white lines you see are the grid lines. You can just turn them off (both x and y-axis) using

```
plt.grid(False)
```

[image]

If you want to show selectively, you can use

```
plt.grid(axis='x')
```

or

```
plt.grid(axis='y')
```